# Python 3.6 tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6

I got through most of the errors but I'm stuck on this one (Which I think will be the last one) if anyone could help that would be great. Thank you

```
import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
```

> Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel, you should
>   not try to import tensorflow from its source directory; please exit
>   the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from
>   there.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I installed it like so `python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: Format your code. Describe how have you installed tensorflow.

Comment: Edited @Ketan /2s

Comment: Assuming there were no errors while installation, could come out of the directory where you installed tensorflow and try `import tensorflow` in python prompt.

Comment: Nope no errors while installing, and import tensorflow returned same error

Comment: did you cd out of the install dir?

Comment: I upgraded to python3.5.3 64 and than I ran into another problem, don't use pycharm to install their tensorflow is outdated.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not directly import module pywrap_tensorflow in Tensorflow 1.0, instead, please try:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

and when you want to use the pywrap_tensorflow module, try:

```
tf.pywrap_tensorflow
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried just doing import tensorflow as tf and it said ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow

Comment: please try `tf.pywrap_tensorflow`, not `tf._pywrap_tensorflow`.